# Node.js - Ask for userInput until condition is met?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am new to Node.js . I am trying to execute following code to repeat the if-then-else loop until user feeds in correct data. However the function is called in the last 'else' but the message is not displayed before the function is called. Can someone please help me with this ?

```
intents.matches('Work type', [
    function xyz(session,args) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session ,"How much is the square feet . Please type \n\n 1 for >2000 sq ft \n\n 2 for <2000 sq ft");
    },
    function abc(session, results) {
        var res = results.response;
        if (res == 1)
            {
                session.send('You can go for Dr. Fixit Newcoat \n Is is a heavy duty terrace waterproof coating system. \n \n 1.Solid Content \n\n 2.Hardness Shore A:  ASTM D 2240 2002 \n\n 3.Tensile Strength N/mm2:ASTM D 412 2002 \n\n 4.Elongation at Break:ASTM D 412 2002 \n\n 5.UV Resistant - Accelerated:ASTM G 154 2000 \n\n Are you satisfied with the solution ?');
            }
        else if (res == 2)
            {
                session.send('You can go for Dr. Fixit New Coat Ezee    \n \n Area of Application- Building roofs/terrace - Flats and Sloping  \n\n OverExisting cementicious waterproofing treatments like \n\n 1.Brickbat \n\n 2.Coba \n\n 3.Concreet screeds \n\n 4.Acrylic coating etc. \n\n Available package : \n\n 1. 4 ltrs : Rs 2000 \n\n 2. 12 ltrs : Rs 5000 \n\n Are you satisfied with the solution ?');   
            }
        else
            {
                session.send('You have entered an in correct input . Please input 1 or 2 as per your requirment');
                abc(session, results);
            }

   }
])
```

Comment: Have you debug/console.log what is being returned?

Comment: I have tried to debug using session.send(''); command. But somehow the function call abc(session, results) and session.send() does not work together. I need to comment either of them to check the flow.

Comment: Can you show the whole example?